# When to show dialogbox

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, activity-lifecycle

So my Application has an Activity A and few other Activities B,C,D etc, all of which opens on different clicks from Activity A.
My requirement is to show a "Enter Pin" DialogBox every time app is opened from outside like (starting app first time, unlocking screen, resuming app after it was paused and other apps were used).

But Dialogbox should not show up when i open and close other Activities (B,C,D etc).

But in both cases, onPause->onStop->onRestart->onResume is called.
So how should i distinguish that whether the user has gone outside the app or not and where should i place my dialog.show()

Comment: Can you ost some code

Comment: @Haroon i have not written any code yet, i am figuring out the data flow right now

Comment: You can achieve that all the code to show dialog will go in Activity A and hence have nothing to with otter activity

Comment: @Haroon i don't think you understood my problem, but thank you for your time.

Comment: i found the solution at [link](http://www.mjbshaw.com/2012/12/determining-if-your-android-application.html), thanks to @xAqweRx for redirecting me there.

Comment: I have unlimited its ok

Answer (score 0):

In `Activity A` do like this,

```
@override
onCreate(){
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
  editor.putBoolean("isRunning", true);
  editor.commit();
}

@override
onStop(){
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
  editor.putBoolean("isRunning", false);
  editor.commit();
}
```

and in `onResume()` check the pref and if `true` then show your dialog.

```
@override
onResume(){

SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
if(pref.getBoolean("isRunning",false)){
    //Show your dialog here
 }

}
```

NOTE : I apologize It's directly written in editor, I'll edit this after being with IDE, But use this logic.

Comment: sorry to say, but this is not the solution, i found the solution here [link](http://www.mjbshaw.com/2012/12/determining-if-your-android-application.html), but thanks for your time.

Comment: @user3024990 Its ok... But have some knowledge. Leave it as it is.. Glad to hear that you found solution.